# Is there a way to store a session variable within the javascript of an AJAX call or only in the method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I have been searching for a bit now but can't find a real answer. What i'm wondering is if there's a possibility to easily search every checkbox on my page and check if it's checked and then send this data to my controller. Personally i was thinkin about simply modyfing the session variable within the AJAX call but i don't see how that's possible(nor have i found anything on internet). Is there anyone who has more experience with this and can help me? Suggestions are welcome even if it's not in the way of session variables.

Comment: I would rather define single method for all checkboxes and set a JavaScript variable to true (if user checked any one). Send server this variable value in Ajax call. And remember this only tells server if any checkbox checked on client side, if they were already checked, server already know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session Variables reside inside the memory of your server and are just identified sometimes by a cookie OR by putting state in the URL. they cannot be changed by javascript on the client side. 
as far as your question goes a simple jquery selector `$('[type="checkbox"]')` would do the job.

```
var $cs = $('[type="checkbox"]')
var o = {};
for(var i=0; i<=$cs.length; i++){
  var $c = $($cs[i]);
  o[$c.attr('name')||$c.attr('id')] = $cs[i].prop('checked'); 
}
```

* this code might have errors i have just typed if here but you will get the picture
** make sure all your checkboxes have either `Id` or `name` attribute

when this code will run you will get the object o as

```
{
 name1 : true,
 name2: false
}
```

Comment: can i still get the name of each individual checkbox though? Cause i do have to know which are checked and which are not

Comment: i'm assuming that in a ASP.net application this would result in a array of strings but i'll see once i'm programming it :P

Comment: @Marijn - you can tweak the answer to form an array of objects with properties name and value and post it to server. this would be easier as asp.net sucks at dynamic model binding

Answer (score 2):

yes you can check if all checkbox on page are checked 
assign some class to them say 'cls'

```
if($('.cls:checked').length == $('.cls').length)
{ 
  //on true ecexute your ajax call to send data to controller
}
```

oh and you cannot modify any session variable in javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you'll want to use a form to submit a set of checked/unchecked boxes. then, on submit, fire off your AJAX request.

HTML:

```
<form id="target">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Dog"> I have a dog<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Cat"> I have a cat<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  // Send your AJAX Request
});
```

Helpful Documentation:

[.submit() | jQuery Documentation Page](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

[jQuery.ajax | jQuery Documentation Page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

try the below codes

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {

                    });



var checkedboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
                var totalboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
                console.log(checkedboxes);
                console.log(totalboxes);
```